# Kotlin flow consumer does not receive events

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I've a problem with kotlin producer/consumer.

I have a method that receive list of elements that should be send to a service in AWS. For do that I have 3 elements:

**-Consumer** -> Reads a kotlin flow and sends each received element to the service

**-Producer** -> Reads a ArrayDequeue each 5 seconds, transform the elements there and send them to a flow.

**-Queue** -> An arrayDequeue

This is the code involved:

```
 private val consumerScope = CoroutineScope(dispatcherProvider.io() + SupervisorJob())
    private val producerScope = CoroutineScope(dispatcherProvider.io() + SupervisorJob())

    private val eventsQueueProducer: Flow<EventLogBatch> = channelFlow {
        while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
            eventsQueue.get()?.let {
                log.error("Producer emitting logs to queue consumers")
                send(it)
            }
            delay(Delay)
        }
    }

    private val eventsQueueConsumer = eventsQueueProducer
        .onEach { event ->
            log.error("Received log events. Sending to backend")
            putLogEvents(requestBuilder.buildRequest(
                logsClient = it,
                logEvents = event.events.sortedBy { event -> event.timestamp }
            ))
        }

    override fun start() {
        eventsQueueConsumer.produceIn(consumerScope)
        eventsQueueProducer.launchIn(producerScope)
    }

    override suspend fun publishEvents(eventLogs: List<EventLog>) {
        eventLogs
            .onEach { log.error("Received event logs to chunk and send") }
            .map { it.toInputLogEvent() }
            .filter { it.message !== null }
            .chunkInMaxSizeBatches()
            .forEach { batch ->
                log.error("Enqueueing new log batch")
                eventsQueue.enqueueLogBatch(batch)
            }
    }
```

My problem is that, events are being sent to the 'producer' channel because I see logs of Producer emitting logs to queue, but I don't see the same number of Received log events. Sending to backend message so my guess is the consumer is not working fine.

Any idea?

Comment: What type is `eventsQueue`? What is the definition of the `produceIn` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you have a misconception about what `channelFlow` does. It creates a *cold* Flow that is backed by a channel *internally*. Since it's a cold flow, it's inappropriate for use as a queue. Every time it's collected, it will start another one of these while loops.

(Incidentally, the way you're using `channelFlow` is pointless. You don't have any parallel coroutines running inside its block, so it provides no advantages over the `flow` builder. The "channel" in "channelFlow" is a backing channel used internally only so you can use parallel coroutines to emit from the flow inside its builder.)

So, you have a cold "producer". And your "consumer" is based on this producer, so the production code is in both of these flows. When you start collection on both of them, then the producer is producing once every 5 seconds, and the consumer is also producing once every 5 seconds before collecting.

The other major potential problem is that if your queue is not built from a thread-safe class, then you could have synchronization bugs. You say it's an ArrayDeque, but I don't know of a parameterless `get()` function for ArrayDeque, so I'm not sure what it is. Most collections are not thread-safe. In a coroutine, you would use Mutex to synchronize something like this.

Ultimately, you should be using Channels, not Flows, for a queue consumption scenario like this. You could potentially use hot SharedFlow, but I think Channels would be simpler and better suited. Although, it also looks like everything just happens internally in this class anyway, so I don't know why you would need any of these structures that separate production and consumption. You could simply have a single loop that consumes directly from the queue.